# Creating a setup project for ASP.NET Core Web API project

Tags: asp.net-core, installation, https, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to preface this by mentioning that I am completely new ASP.NET and this project type. So please bare with me as I am in very unfamiliar territory.

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project that I had completed. It works fine when I use the debugger and swagger to check its functionality. However, I was unable to find any tutorials on how to create a setup project for it (or at least none that my limited understanding could work out).

The intention of this setup project is to hand off an installer (like a .msi, .exe or something similar) to a third party with very little coding know-how could just, with a few clicks, have it installed and deployed. I had specifically used this tutorial when making the original application:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

Would anyone be able to provide any tutorials, information, or materials on how I may accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

> I was unable to find any tutorials on how to create a setup project
> for it (or at least none that my limited understanding could work
> out).

Well, I think you got it wrong, [installer package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022) or [Windows Installer package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022) (MSI or EXE installation file) usually target for desktop based app. You can [check here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022#create-a-setup-project)

[image]

Unlike desktop app,  ASP.NET Core itself doesn't have a built-in mechanism for creating setup or installation processes like Windows Forms applications or any other desktop based application. Because, they interact via the browser, web applications don't require installation on each user's device. Users access them through URLs, eliminating the need for an installation process.

Web applications often rely on various external resources like databases or cloud services, making a single, self-contained installer impractical. Consequently, web like asp.net core Web API or MVC app doesn't requrie setup wizerd or there's no such way in in visual studio.

> Would anyone be able to provide any tutorials, information, or
> materials on how I may accomplish this?

As said, for asp.net core web api or MVC app, as it only can be publised either in local deployment or server (like IIS or Azure), so there's no official guideline for that.

**Note:** You can [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components?view=vs-2022#create-an-installer-package-windows-desktop), but you can only create installer package for [desktop application only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components?view=vs-2022#create-an-installer-package-windows-desktop).